# Limitations to Bitwise Systems

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have just taken some online tutorials on how Bits work. Though I have a couple of questions. I have searched the internet but didn't find what i was looking for. I may have been searching for some incorrect key words.

Lets say i wish to build an option or permission system using bitwise (i think that is the correct terminology). I have the following hestitations:

1) Is it possible to end up with collisions when using & etc?

2) If there is collision opportunities what sort of steps should i take when im designing my permissions? Does the permission numbers change if i have a considerably large set of permissions e.g. over 500?

Hopefully i got my question across correctly, if not please let me know and i will try to rephrase.

EDIT::
Similar Question here which i believe has been answered

[User role permissions for different modules using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925245/user-role-permissions-for-different-modules-using-bitwise-operators?rq=1)

Comment: For instance the following website is one of the sites I used to learn bitwise operations. http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm.

Near the bottom it provides an example, how would i be able to use ~500 permissions since the numbers will keep going up and up. Permissions include view/add/edit/delete for about 100 different sections of a website?

Comment: 500 permissions? How on earth can you end up with so many, I personally never managed to exceed a byte..

Comment: It is possible if you tap into dynamic content. Unless the count would be reset since it can technically be labelled as its own "group".

Comment: Usually when you use bits to store permission data, you have something like read, write, delete which fits 3 bits.. if you have 500 permissions, you have 500 different flags that determine a possible action over the resource which indicates you might be going wrong way about this?

Comment: @N.B. - one of the ways that 'bit fields' can be so big is when you have huge sources of data but you'll only send a subset of them.  It's not unusual then to have a long string at the beginning of the data like '1100011101010100010110001' followed by all the data values (perhaps CSV) ", x, y, z, a, b, c, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60".  This way you only send as much data as necessary please a header that defines what data is coming.  Kind of a sparse matrix....

Answer (score 1):

1. What kind of collisions?
2. For 500 different permissions, you'd have to store 500 bits. There's no computers in existence which can directly handle a 500+bit value. With bit systems, you're basically restricted to using what the underlying cpu can provide, e.g. 8, 16, 32, 64-bit sized values. Anything beyond that has to be split into multiple different memory chunks.

e.g.

```
permission_flags && (1 << 475)
```

is going to fail on every platform in existence, because once you shift past bit #63, you're past what the cpu can directly support.

Comment: You mean `permission_flags & (1 << 475)` (single `&` instead of double); also it will not fail _in an obvious way_, it will simply evaluate to zero.

Comment: "There's no computers in existence which can directly handle a 500+bit value" - actually [Intel's Xeon Phi aka MIC aka Knight's Corner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MIC) has 512 bit SIMD and supports 512 bit bitwise operations on vector registers.

Comment: @paul r: phew. cool stuff. But either way, doing 500+ permissions flags using bitwise operations is just borderline insane.

Comment: Sure - but who can resist when it comes to geek pedantry? ;-)

Comment: @PaulR 512 bit *SIMD*, so it still can't do the shift, only the and.

Comment: @harold: well that's not an inherent limitation of SIMD *per se* (e.g. AltiVec has shift instructions which can be applied to a full vector), but you're right in the case of MIC - it only supports shifts on 32 bit and 64 bit elements.